# Intellij IDEA: How to select code (folding) block with keyboard?

Tags: intellij-idea, editor, phpstorm, webstorm

Example dummy code:

```
body {
    background: white;
}
```

How can I select this whole code block with one shortcut? Best if caret should be `|body`, or `body {|`, or just on the desired row.

There is "Move Caret to Code Block End/Start with Selection" command, but it actually doesn't select `body` and `}`. So in next step you can't indent whole block by <kbd>Tab</kbd>. And it doesn't really fit for this task.

Answer (score 5):

https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/selecting-text-in-the-editor.html#d746177e148
You can use `extend selection`  This is very useful feature. In you case create macro:

- move to start block
- extend selection
- extend selection
- extend selection

And bind this macro to shortcut.